# Swift how to override the 3D-Touch functions correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

I'm currently trying to implement 3D touch in my own little app. The app is something like a school planner so that the main view Controller is an UITableViewController, there are some lessons in a table view, and when clicking on one of them, a segue will appear and will change the active view controller to the 'DetailedViewController'.swift . Everything works so far. But now I'm trying to implement 3D-Touch so that a user can press on a 'lesson' harder to get a preview of the specific lesson. My first try was to just set the checkmark in the storyboard's segue. It actually showed the preview, but I want to add some actions beneath the preview, and give it a title. So I tried to implement the UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate protocol and create my custom functions.

But from then on, I have no idea how to continue.

My functions:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    // .... Some other irrelevant stuff
    registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView: view)
}

 func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location) {
        //This will show the cell clearly and blur the rest of the screen for our peek.
        previewingContext.sourceRect = tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    }
    return nil
}

func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commitViewController viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
    presentViewController(viewControllerToCommit, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func previewActionItems() -> [UIPreviewActionItem] {
    print("previewActionItems")
    let action = UIPreviewAction(title: "Press Me!", style: .Default) { (action, viewController) in
        print("I believe I can fly")
    }
    return [UIPreviewAction](arrayLiteral: action)
}
```

And my classes:

Initial view controller is MainTableViewController. All functions shown above are written in this class.

The more detailed view controller is the DetailedViewController.

Thank you for an answer!

Comment: it's a good idea to watch the WWDC session(s) on the topic

Comment: Yeah i know... But I just want to get an answer to my question right now xD

Comment: You might want to look at this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-an-introduction-to-3d-touch--cms-25115) . There you can find both programmatical and storyboard solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
override var previewActionItems: [UIPreviewActionItem] {

    let action1 = UIPreviewActionGroup(title: NSLocalizedString("action1", comment: "action1"), style: .default, actions: someAction)

    let action2 = UIPreviewAction(title: "action2", style: .default) {[unowned self] (action, viewController) in
        print("action2")
    }

    return [action1, action2]
}
```